# How can I retrieve record without having to select the item and click in the input

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am working on a jquery-ui autocomplete. I can start typing and from the first letter, a dropdown appears with matches. That part works correctly. My problem is, when you make a selection from the dropdown. I have tried `onchange` and `onselect` and they don't work. The code that gets the closest is `onclick`, but once you select an entry from the dropdown, in order for the script to retrieve the record from the database, you have to click again in the text input. Here is the code I described:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
source: 'server.php'
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="ui-widget"> 
<input type="text" id="autocomplete" name="search" onclick="showMember(this.value)">
</div>
</div>
<div id="txtHint"></div>
<script>
function showMember(str) {
if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else { 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","catlist.php?name="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
}
</script>
```

`server.php` gets the data for the dropdown :

```
$connect=mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
$db=mysql_select_db($databasename);

$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];

$select =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cmsb_markers WHERE name LIKE '".$searchTerm."%'");
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($select)) 
{
$data[] = $row['name'];
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

And `catlist.php` retrieves the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>jQuery Tests</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(function(){
            $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
                search: function( event, ui ) {
                    $('.loader').show();
                },
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        method: "get",
                        url: "server.php",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {
                            q: request.term
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('.loader').hide();
                            response(data);
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                            var msg = '';
                            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                                msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
                            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                                msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
                            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                                msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
                            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                                msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
                            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                                msg = 'Time out error.';
                            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                                msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
                            } else {
                                msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
                            }
                            alert(msg);
                        },
                    });
                },
                minLength: 1,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#autocomplete").val(ui.item ? ui.item.name : "");
                    showMember(ui.item.name);
                    return false;
                },
                change: function (event, ui) {
                    if (!ui.item) {
                        $("#autocomplete").val("");
                        $("#txtHint").val("");
                    }
                }
            }).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                return $("<li>").append("<a>" + item.name + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
            };

            function showMember(str) {
                if (str == "") {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
                    return;
                } else { 
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    } else {
                        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                        }
                    };
                    xmlhttp.open("GET","catlist.php?name="+str,true);
                    xmlhttp.send();
                }
            }
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="ui-widget"> 
                <input type="text" id="autocomplete" name="search" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="txtHint"></div>
    </body>
</html>


<?php
//server.php
$connect=mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
$db=mysql_select_db($databasename);

$searchTerm = $_GET['q'];

$select =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cmsb_markers WHERE name LIKE '".$searchTerm."%'");
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($select)) {
    $data[] = array("name" => $row['name']);
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove onselect method from yout HTML node as below:

```
<input type="text" id="autocomplete" name="search">
```

And, add onselect event on your autocomplete function like below:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
        source: 'server.php',
        onSelect: showMember(e, term, item)
     });
});
```

Here you need to get your current selected item value from passed parameter of onSelect method. You also need to do modification accordingly in showMember function as well. Hope it helps you.